# Spectrum of Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse multiplied by a constant

Tags: matrices, probability-distributions, random-matrices, eigenvalues

Consider a random rectangular matrix $X\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times P}$ where each entry is drawn from iid distribution with mean $m$ and variance $s^2$, and denote $X^+$ the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse.

What is the distribution of the eigenvalues $\rho(\lambda_{A X^+})$ of:

$$A X^+ = A (X'X)^{-1} X'$$

for a constant $A\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times P}$, where $N,P \to \infty$ with constant ratio $\alpha=P/N$?

Comment: posted simultaneously at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4734531/87355 --- please don't

Comment: see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/5013/11260

Comment: deleted the other post, thanks